# Backlit keyboard only lights up after Windows sign-in

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I have had no joy in all forums regarding this issue. It seems also to affect Apple users (where the FileVault has to be deactivated).

How can I get the keyboard on my Asus UX301LA (Win10) to remain lit up after booting the device and entering sign-in screen?

When pressing the power button to boot up, there is a brief light-up of the keyboard and when it enters the sign-in screen the keyboard goes dark....which is counterintuitive, as I need to see it when signing in if I am in a dark room. This is quite annoying sometimes.

Anyway, thanks for any advice...

Comment: Which brand and model laptop are you using?

Comment: Asus Zenbook UX301LA (Win10). But the same issue was also with the work laptop, which was a Lenovo Thinkpad. The keyboard would only light up after sign-in. Could it be a Win 10 issue?

Comment: Did you try Fn+ space button to turn on and off the light of keyboard

Comment: For Asus laptop you need to install ATK package and keyboard filter to be install.. if it not available for Windows 10 website try to download windows 8 version this utility.. and try with Fn + f3 or f4 to set back light.. if this didn't work you have use BT utility and set the backlight to be turned on

Comment: Hi Techie, I cannot seem to attach the screenshots here to demo what happens. However, when I boot the laptop the keyboard briefly goes on and then off when it comes to the sign-in screen. When I then sign in, the keyboard goes back on again. I have ATK installed and when I reinstall it it says "latest version already installed". I can set the level of keyboard backlit at low, medium, and high as well using the Fn key and F3/F4. All that works fine.

Comment: You have use BT utility. Boot from that utiily and set the keyboard backlight on via command

Answer (score 0):

You Can try with BT Utility.

1. Download latest ATKACPI Driver and Keyboard Filter Utility.
2. If Above Doesn't Work, Use Asus Powerful Bios Tool BT Utility.

   - **Be extra careful when using Asus BT Utility, I am not responsible for
     any damage!**

---

1. Download BT Utility [Download BT Utilty](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zRvOw8HzDuM293N05fTENwY00)
2. Make it bootable Using Rufus [Download Latest Version](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)
3. Run Rufus and Insert Pen Drive(Thumb Drive) Size 2GB or 4GB is enough.
4. Make a Bootable drive with FreeDOS.(make sure Filesystem is FAT32) Follow the image below.

[image: Screenshot of Rufus free dos bootable]

5. Once you complete Free Dos Bootable. Unzip BT_Utility_TechieGosip.zip **Copy The BT.exe to Bootable Drive.**
6. Restart your laptop. Boot from Pen drive.
7. Free DOS Language selection will appear. Select English. Once you see `C:\>`
8. Run the Command `BT -c cnfg /ww dd 7c`
9. You get result about some kind of writing error, for the first time at the end you see `Return 0. It is OK. Do Control+Alt+Del (reboot) your PC Twice. Check Back light should work in BIOS.

Hope this will work

Comment: Hi Techie thanks a lot for your instructions. I'll try that and will let you know.

Comment: Hope so this will work